# Detect ideal socket connection

Tags: c, linux, epoll

We have a single threaded server that uses `epoll` to detect new connections and incoming data on the existing socket connections. Everything is working fine.

However, we don't want to keep connection ideal. We'd like to disconnect the connection if no data is received in say, 10 seconds.

Is there a way in `epoll` so that event is generated if no data is received in some time. Any other way can you recommend. Note that the server has to be single threaded and number of sockets are large (10-20K).

Comment: well `epoll_wait `has a timeout, why dont you use it?